# Set zoomScale for CMV search widget

Tags: zoom, configurable-map-viewer, search

I would like to change the zoomScale parameters for the selected search item.  The widget currently zooms in to far for the area I need to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I make this sort of thing configurable in my widgets but did not in this case. I will correct that so you can adjust it for each search. I will edit my answer when that is completed.

In the meantime, you can edit the source code to modify one or two values that are currently hard-coded.

For a single point, it builds an extent around the point with using 250 meters (or feet) around the point. Change it to a larger value to zoom out further. That is modified here: https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/AttributesTable/_GraphicsMixin.js#L619

If you want the map to zoom further for all features, you can modify the scale passed to the expand method of the extent. Change the 1.5 to 2 or 3 or whatever fits best. That is modified here: https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/widgets/AttributesTable/_GraphicsMixin.js#L597

Comment: I changed this.pointExtentSize = 5000; & this.map.setExtent(extent.expand(1.0));. It works perfectly.  Thank you once again.